# Files auto-loaded into Rails env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, helper

I'm having some difficulty understanding the rules for when files are auto-loaded into Rails application vs when they need to be manually required. For example, one has to require 'rails_helper' generally for controller test, but not for feature tests (at least by default). Another example: User model class is accessible from Rake tasks..

None of the view helpers need to be required, and oftentimes requiring something will break the program. Can someone help me understand / know when I'm supposed to require something vs trusting that it is auto loaded?

I know that I'm able to configure what files are autoloaded from config/application.rb, but am trying to understand what comes with the Rails env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Rails 5 Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html), all files under the `app/` and `config/` path are autoloaded.
You could then create a `app/lib` subfolder where you can put your classes and modules.

A rake task will load these files only if you declare it calling the environment, e.g.:

```
desc 'My task name'
rake task_name: :environment do
  # Do something
end
```

Did you mean anything more specific?

Comment: Awesome--thanks! What about spec files?  I find myself having to require 'rails_helper' sometimes in my spec module helper files?

Comment: So this means anything I have in app/ and config/ I wouldn't need to manually require ANYWHERE in the rails application? even if referenced outside of those folders?

And if I have the :environment tag on my rake task, then ALL files are autoloaded under app/ and config/?

Comment: Yes it is! Did it work for you? If it is the case, please check the answer and close the topic :)